# Is there a C++ framework for Web Development similar to Laravel 4 for PHP or an MVC framework?

Tags: web-development, c++, web-server

I'm looking for a C++ framework that will manage files, like serving a JS file included in an html document.

It won't just be serving static pages though.

Essentially I would like it to send static html and javascript at first, then the javascript will create a socket connection with the server to query for data and receive updates to data.

I ask for something similar to laravel, because that is what I have the most experience with.  And by like Laravel, I mean is there a way to route based on the uri to have different controller methods handle different requests/and at the same time automatically handle file request uri's for fetching static documents, like javascript and css.

I've looked into POCO, and I don't believe it has these capabilities unless I'm mistaken.  I've also seen people recommending cgi and CSP.   Are these good ideas or is there something better?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check out the dragon framework

Comment: If you are ok with C# instead of C++, you may go for ASP.NET (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this? No personal experience, but could be good.
https://cutelyst.org/
C++ is generally not used for web development, so not as many good options.